# Old input-text-values in div when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript/innerHTML-problem. To make it easier to understand I have written this code:

```
<div id="testdiv_from">
<input type="text" id="text1" value="13"/>
</div>

<div id="testdiv_to">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="save();"/>

<script>
function save() {
document.getElementById("testdiv_to").innerHTML = document.getElementById("testdiv_from").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

I want to copy the content in **testdiv_from** to **testdiv_to**. But: If I change the value on the input text-element from 13 to 14, the new value doesn't want to "accompany".

Do you have any ideas how to transfer the new input-text-values and not the old ones inside the div layer? Is it wrong to use innerHTML?

http://jsfiddle.net/r8z55/

Comment: If you look at input element in Developer tools, you will see that input element is a wrapper of hidden div element, so when you changing value of input it's not changed it's attribute, instead it's changing that hidden div element.

Comment: Is there no way to transfer the changed values to the other div?

Comment: Yes, there is. Look at answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at input element in Developer tools, you will see that input element is a wrapper of hidden div element, so when you change value of input element, its changes value of hidden div element, and not an attribute.

If you want to copy content of one element into another element, would be better if you use standard DOM property/methods, such as [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).

[***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/r8z55/4/)

```
function save() {
    var divTo = document.getElementById("testdiv_to"),
        divFrom = document.getElementById("testdiv_from");
    // since, you said that you have multiple input elements that you want to copy,
    // you should loop through each node and clone it.
    [].forEach.call(divFrom.childNodes, function (node) {
        // the difference between innerHTML and node.cloneNode(true) is that
        // cloneNode with "deep copy", copies that hidden element too.
        divTo.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true)); 
    });
}
```

*FYI:* If you want to copy an element, you shouldn't add `id` attribute to those elements, since `id` ought to be unique per document. Instead, add class or change `id` while cloning.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the `innerHTML` the attributes (including `value=`) come with it. Changing the value you see in the input doesn't change the attribute, just the property. You can change it afterwards though:

```
function save() {
   var inp1 = document.getElementById("testdiv_to"),
       inp2 = document.getElementById("testdiv_from");
   inp1.innerHTML = inp2.innerHTML;
   inp1.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = inp2.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/r8z55/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, this came up at the top of my search and there were no other relevant results, so I'll post an answer here for future searchers.

I tried using Node.cloneNode, but did not have much luck (could be the browser, Firefox, that I'm using).  Then after a lot of testing with print statements I figured out how to do what the questioner is asking.

It's quite simple:  in your onchange event handler, use:
e.target.setAttribute("value", e.target.value);

So it looks like the "value" attribute of the input tag is different from the .value property in JS.  One is HTML, the other must be internal.  So using "setAttribute" changes the HTML attribute value.  Then you can access and save all the changed input fields using the innerHTML property.

EDIT:  Oh, and now it makes sense why Node.cloneNode didn't help to access the changed input fields.  If the original input tags did not have the changed attribute values which would allow you to access the new user input, then neither would the clones.  You'd just be cloning the old, incorrect attribute values.